# How to get DST offset with Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

In my java program I do something like this

1.)

```
LocalDateTime currentDateTime = new LocalDateTime();

LocalDateTime newDateTime = new LocalDateTime(currentDateTime);
newDateTime = newDateTime.plusDays(daysOffset);
newDateTime = newDateTime.plusHours(hoursOffset);
newDateTime = newDateTime.plusMinutes(minutesOffset);
```

Later in the code I do

2.)

```
boolean newDateTimeIsInWinter =
                    dateTimeZone.getOffset(newDateTime.toDateTime().getMillis()) == dateTimeZone.getStandardOffset(newDateTime.toDateTime().getMillis());
```

The of call `newDateTime.toDateTime()` may result `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition`.

So I'd like to put something like this between 1.) and 2.)

```
if (dateTimeZone.isLocalDateTimeGap(newDateTime))
{
    int dstOffsetMinutes = ???;
    newDateTime = newDateTime.plusMinutes(dstOffsetMinutes);
}
```

Can anyone tell me the right replacement for `???` It's not as easy as setting it to `60`. For example the LHST timezone hast only 30 Minutes offset.

Answer (score 1):

## Ask `DateTimeZome` About DST

To determine if a particular moment is in Daylight Saving Time or not for a particular time zone, ask the [`DateTimeZone][1]` object.

```
boolean isStandardTime = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ).isStandardOffset( DateTime.now().getMillis() );
```

## When To Use "Local" Classes

If you care about time zone, offsets, and Daylight Saving Time, do *not* use `LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate`, or `LocalTime`. That is what `DateTime` is for.

Use the "Local" classes when you mean a date and/or time *in general* not for a specific place or time zone. For example if you want to say “Christmas starts at 2014-12-25T00:00:00.000" that means at midnight on the morning of the 25th at any particular location. But that `LocalDateTime` could mean one `DateTime` for Paris but a different `DateTime` (different moment) in Montréal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about LocalDateTime and DateTime. But my question "How long is the dstOffset" is still open

Answer (score 0):

I **solved my problem** by using DateTime instead LocalDateTime

1.) now is

```
DateTime newDateTimeUTC = currentDateTime.toDateTime();
newDateTimeUTC = newDateTimeUTC.plusDays(daysOffset);
newDateTimeUTC = newDateTimeUTC.plusHours(hoursOffset);
newDateTimeUTC = newDateTimeUTC.plusMinutes(minutesOffset);

LocalDateTime newDateTime = newDateTimeUTC.toLocalDateTime();
```

2.) still is

```
boolean newDateTimeIsInWinter =
    dateTimeZone.getOffset(newDateTime.toDateTime().getMillis()) == dateTimeZone.getStandardOffset(newDateTime.toDateTime().getMillis());
```

There is no need for `isLocalDateTimeGap` or anything else.

But this still does not anwser the original question *How to get DST offset with Joda Time?*